# Win 10 recording game flickers

Tags: windows-10, recording, rocket-league

I want to record some gameplay, Rocket League, but once I press WIN+G the recording build in the XBOX App doesn't open. The screen becomes lighter, normal, lighter and back to normal. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Windows recorder sometimes don't recognize some games. My recomendation to record a game with free software is:

1. If you have Nvidia grafic card use "nvidia shadowplay" to record games
2. Else if you have AMD grafic card you can use "amd gaming evolved".
3. Finally if you can´t use this software you can use Dxtory or Fraps.